# A spaceship called the Fruitfly, piloted by a character called Fur

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

I read it as a child and it was one of the best books I ever read. On the cover it had a black hand holding a crystal.

I remember the plot goes as follows:

Four kids, (three boys and a girl, I think) are playing in the woods when they find a crystal being held by a black hand that I think extended from a tree.

They take it, and I remember the hand closed again, stopping them from putting it back.

Somehow they find out it can grant wishes and so they all wish for things. One wishes for a million dollars, and it appears. I remember him stuffing as many dollars as he could into his pockets. The girl wishes for the most powerful shield in the universe. The other boy wishes for a laser gun and the last boy wishes for galactic peace.

A collector robot then appears, and sentences them to hard labour on a prison planet called Amacron 7, or something like that, in payment for their wishes. A desert planet.

The rest of the details are hazy, but they are rescued by an alien called Fur, who liked to eat fruitflies with a drink of Coke. He had a ship called the Fruitfly.

I've made it sound terrible but I remember it was excellent. Any ideas guys?

Comment: I found _[The Wishing Stone](http://books.google.nl/books/about/The_Wishing_Stone.html?id=scV0AQAAQBAJ&redir_esc=y)_ by Christopher Pike, but that would be too easy, would it? I mean, I only Googled.

Comment: Oh smeg, wish I was as good googling as you! I think that might be it...

Comment: Oh, I found another link, that's better. I'll write it up as an answer.

Comment: @MrLister - Better hurry up. The vultures are circling (me, for instance)

Comment: @Richard Can't you leave the easy ones to us lesser gods?

Comment: @MrLister - No.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is *The Wishing Stone* by Christopher Pike, part 9 in the Spooksville series.

The [preview in Google Books](http://books.google.nl/books?id=scV0AQAAQBAJ&pg=PT32&lpg=PT32&dq=wishing+stone+christopher+pike+fruitfly&source=bl&ots=rknDcCJa6n&sig=ZHupjIiuUFQBI6dCVvOItsO07ZU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Uqh8VIKUMsGwPNrFgZgK&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=wishing%20stone%20christopher%20pike%20fruitfly&f=false)  shows that there is a black hand holding a cube shaped crystal and an alien named Fur with a spaceship named Fruitfly. Oh, and Amacron thirty-seven.

Comment: Quite impressed that the word 'Amacron' has been floating about my neurons for over a decade :P