# Whatever happened to Superman's super powered moa?

Tags: comics, dc, superman, animals

There once was a super powered [moa](http://fc05.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2014/076/0/e/moa_by_sameerprehistorica-d7ajpit.jpg), and comic book Superman did battle with it and managed to capture it unharmed just near the end of the issue. What did Superman do with the beast?

Comment: What issue did he fight the moa?

Comment: @Thunderforge I have no idea. :(

Comment: @Thunderforge - Action Comics #425.

Comment: Wow, WTF. I guess this just proves that *everything* has happened in a superhero comic at some point.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is [Action Comics #425](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Action_Comics_Vol_1_425) - "*The Last Moa on Earth*".

**Strange gases affect the last moa egg**

[image]

**The moa drains the hunter's life forces, growing to an enormous size within hours**

[image]

**Superman fights the beast which can now fly and has become psychic.**

[image]

**Before finally realising that the animal simply wants to go home**

[image]

Since there are no further mentions of this animal, I think we can assume **it lived the remainder of its life in peace and tranquility near the pond**

Comment: ...you win this time

Comment: It's not about winning or losing, it's about [delivering high quality answers to the OP](http://static.fjcdn.com/gifs/Sheep+take+revenge+on+farmer_5499f5_4300809.gif).

Comment: @Richard: Gamification is a big part of how SE was structured to produce that end result.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Richard knows that, and his remark is tongue-in-cheek. See also [this meta discussion](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/7360/4495).

Comment: @MrLister: I see [you've had the exact same problem](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7360/is-scifi-stackexchange-com-a-competition#comment19922_7360). Anyway, I'm sure he can speak for himself!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Sure; I just want to leave [this](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/73847/a-spaceship-called-the-fruitfly-piloted-by-a-character-called-fur#comment154736_73847) here and then let's call it a day.

Comment: @MrLister: See, it _is_ about winning or losing ;)

Comment: I'd like to see the protective fence. I'd like to have seen Superman ride the bird into battle. But, no.

Answer (score 6):

#### It's most probably in his [Fortress of Solitude](https://www.google.ie/search?q=superman+fortress+of+solitude&client=ms-android-h3g-ie&prmd=ivn&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjN5_TE25zMAhVDBBoKHSSFDoYQ_AUIBygB&biw=360&bih=511&dpr=3#tbm=isch&q=superman+fortress+of+solitude+inside&imgrc=hGyYYiCeGXIk4M%3A)

Superman has a handy *Interplanetary Habitat* area in his fortress. He's such a good guy, he can't just kill every super powered creature he battles, so they usually end up here.

I'm unable to find a specific reference to the moa in question, but he's very likely here.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, that's it son. We took him to the far...er...habitat...where he can run free.

Comment: So you reckon Superman had super-moa nuggets for dinner...

Comment: @Richard - Unfortunately for the moa, they were [quite delicious](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moa#Extinction).

Comment: @T.E.D. - Hence the lyrics of the song "Rebel Yell". It's about a craving for moa burgers.